# How to reduce asp.net core project docker runtime image size

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I've just added a Dockerfile to my simple asp.net core demo [project](https://github.com/MackHog/WebAppDockerDemo).

When i run

```
docker build -f .\deploy\Dockerfile -t coreapp .
```

It results in a image of 1,35GB..

[image]

Docker version (docker for windows)

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:21:34 2018
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:36:40 2018
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /build
COPY . /build

#Restore
RUN dotnet restore ./WebAppDockerDemo.sln

RUN dotnet publish ./src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj --output /publish --configuration Release

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Why is the image so large? I thought the runtime image I create would be around 2-300MB.. I checked different examples, [1](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-app-dockerfiles/), but can't find what's wrong here.

How can I reduce the size?

Comment: I think the base windows image is pretty large vs using linux containers. You could try nanoserver https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2018/06/new-windows-container-image/

Comment: @JoeAudette thx for the link. In almost every example I've seen the manage to get the final project runtime image under 300MB. They even had the same setup as me..guess im to n00b on this still, will investigate more

Comment: Docker for windows lets you use either windows containers or linux containers but not both. Most tutorials I've seen use linux containers, the smallest aspnet core linux container I've seen is for alpine linux. I It looks like you are using windows containers which are larger in general. Not sure if there is a nanoserver image for aspnetcore, but you could google that.

Comment: I just ran your exact example on my Linux OS and it's coming out at 253MB. That's the exact same size as the `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime` itself too.

Comment: @KirkLarkin and JoeAudette thx for the help. Docker for windows (running in linux server) works on client machines only, check this post https://forums.docker.com/t/build-linux-containers-on-docker-for-windows-server-2016/55270/4.. Will investigate more later